# How do I output if there is data in the array?

Tags: php, arrays, database, if-statement

I have an array like this in PHP:

```
$myarray = ['mango','jackfruit','litchi','apple','banana'];
```

I want, if there is 'litchi' in the array data then it will show "This is litchi".
But, how to do it?

Comment: Hint: `in_array()`.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4768e956d9ef8965d28831f623b1c19cc5d56279

Comment: Thank you brother. Now, my project is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will print `This is litchi` if the value `litchi` is in the array `$myarray`:

```
$myarray = ['mango', 'jackfruit', 'litchi', 'apple', 'banana'];

if (in_array('litchi', $myarray)) {
  echo 'This is litchi';
}
```